# WiX standard bootstrapper application (burn) - image sizes

Tags: wix

I'm following this extract from wixtoolset.org - [Changing the WiX Standard Bootstrapper Application Branding](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/wixstdba_branding.html) as I'm using the HyperlinkSidebarLicense UI.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <Bundle>
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkSidebarLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
        LicenseUrl="License.htm"
        LogoFile="path\to\customlogo.png" LogoSideFile="path\to\customsidelogo.png"
        />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>
      ...
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

However, I can't seem to find any reference to what size the PNG files need to be.

Has anyone worked with the bootstrapper before who can advise here?

Answer (score 14):

According to the images included in the [source](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/BalExtension/wixstdba/Resources), it looks like...

- LogoFile is 64x64
- LogoSideFile is 165x400

Answer (score 0):

The size of these can be found in the corresponding wix theme files:
  - RtfTheme.xml
  - HyperlinkLicenseTheme.xml
  - FoundationTheme.xml

depending on which one you are using, I'm not sure if they vary per theme but that is where the sizes are located.

Note (I believe this is a bug but I'm not sure): If you try to copy the themes into your own theme and modify theme image names at all, the wix solution will not start.

Using the properties in the WixStandardBootstrapperApplication, We also have another solution that uses a 64x64 for LogoFile but a 128x128 LogoSideFile.  So once again I'm left slightly confused about WiX.

Your mileage may vary.